# Are there restrctions on the number of mosques in a given area?

Tags: masjid, jumuah

Are there restrictions on the number of mosques in a given area? For example, is it permissible to build 3 mosques in a small village? Can Friday prayers take place at all 3 mosques at the same time?

Comment: Note that the Friday prayer is supposed to be a communal not private event, jurists have recorded the condition that there must be only one Friday congregation even in a big city, unless it is impractical.

Answer (score -1):

as I know, there is no limitation. 
For Friday prayer, it must be at least a quorum of 12 prayers (I'm not sure if the Imam is counted or not, but I think so) for the Imam to do the Friday preach.

If with 3 mosques in the same village, there are enough prayers for 3 preachs, I think it is permissible.